# boot a linux live cd in VmWare

Tags: linux, vmware-workstation, live-cd

On a windows host system, I have VmWare workstation installed and I need to boot a linux guest LiveCD in VmWare. How do I do this? Can you please post instrutions for both physical cd drive and iso disk image?

Answer (score 4):

The instructions are really incredibly simple:

Taken from [https://www.petri.co.il/use-iso-image-files-vmware.htm](https://www.petri.com/use-iso-image-files-vmware):

> To mount an ISO file in VMware
>   Workstation or Server, go to your
>   existing Virtual Machine. Double-click
>   on the CD-ROM drive like this:
>   [image]
>
> Or, inside VMware, go to VM ->
>   Settings and click on CD/DVD drive.
>   Here, you will seen the "Connection"
>   properties for this device. By
>   default, you are probably using the
>   "physical driver". To change that and
>   use a disk image, click on Use ISO
>   Image, like this:
>   [image]
>   <sub>(source: [petri.co.il](https://www.petri.co.il/images/iso-images-vmware-02.jpg))</sub>
>
> Click Browse, browse to the name of
>   your .ISO file, and click Open.
>
> This will fill in the path to your ISO
>   file, like this:
>    [image]
>
> Now, click Connect at power on and OK.
>
> At this point the ISO is ready for use
>   by the OS. This demonstration was done
>   with the VM not running but this
>   operation can be performed on VMs
>   while they are running (just like you
>   would taking a CD/DVD in and out of
>   the CD/DVD drive on your PC).
>
> Here, you can see that the mounting
>   was successful:
>   [image]
>
> As you can see, this Windows Server
>   has a CD drive mounted, even though it
>   has no physical CD/DVD drive. From
>   here, I could install operating system
>   upgrades or additional features.

To use a physical disc instead of an ISO, check the option for "Use physical drive".

Comment: This is all true, but how do you then get the linux guest OS to boot to the ISO? I'm assuming we need a new entry in grub.conf on the guest, because the liveCD still doesn't show up in the boot menu.

Comment: @dmohr - well that's a totally different question. You might want to enter the BIOS settings in the VM to change the default boot device to the CD first.

Comment: This helps on how to change boot order in BIOS: http://superuser.com/questions/65067/how-do-i-force-vmware-virtual-machine-to-enter-the-bios-setup